# How that JavaScript will resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using some node.js code and there is one line in that code.
Can any one help me how that following javascript code will resolve?

```
var silent = 'test' == process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

why that code use = and == at one line?
I guess its a kind for shorthand coding style but I do not know what will be its full-form.

Comment: It could have been more clearly written `var silent = ('test' == process.env.NODE_ENV);`, which is equivalent.

Comment: `==` is a shorthand assignment for … - uh, no, it's clearly a [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: This question is not much more interesting than understanding the JS statement `var a = b + c;`. The correct answer would likely be "I guess you don't know `==` is an operator, go look it up."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var`, variable declaration statement works from the left most expression to the right. The left hand side expression is evaluated first and then the right hand side expression. So, it creates a variable `silent` and then assigns the result of the comparison to it.

Parenthesis would have helped to understand this better,

```
var silent = ('test' == process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

This checks if the environmental variable `NODE_ENV` is equal to `"test"` or not. And the boolean result will be used to initialize the newly created variable `silent`, at runtime.

Comment: "Associativity" refers to the way operators of the same precedence are handled in cases such as `a + b + c`. That is not applicable here, since the two operators `=` and `==` have different precedence. (Associativity would be relevant in the case of `a = b = c`; the right-to-left associativity of `=` means that would be parsed as `a = (b = c)`). The correct description of this situation would be to say "`=` has **lower precedence** than `==`." That is why the expression involving `==` is evaluated first, and the assignment with that as its RHS is evaluated next.

Comment: @torazaburo Well, you are correct. I couldn't find the right words to describe it. I reworded that sentence now, please check.

Answer (score 1):

It will resolve to a boolean value ( `true`/ `false` ):

```
// if process.env.NODE_ENV is 'test'
var silent = 'test' == process.env.NODE_ENV;
console.log(silent); // true

// if process.env.NODE_ENV is 'production'
var silent = 'test' == process.env.NODE_ENV;
console.log(silent); // false
```

The developer is doing this for semantic value. He could done:

```
var silent;
if ('test' == process.env.NODE_ENV){
    silent = true;
}
else {
    silent = false;
}
```

but this is less succinct and poignant.